# Localhost MAMP Mac

Tags: localhost, mamp

I'm having an issue with my local server through MAMP. Everything works, however when I make a change and save, it does not appear in the browser. I refresh / reload, but it takes a varying amount of time. Sometimes it appears instantly, and other times It can take a few minutes.

Thank you,

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix it try this:  in your hosts file you need to list all your local dev sites in a space delimited row like so...

127.0.0.1 localhost localsite1.dev localsite2.dev localsite3.dev

Comment: Where does one locate the hosts file?

Comment: The Hosts file is located at:

/private/etc/hosts

Open the Terminal. 

Enter the following command:
sudo nano /private/etc/hosts